# Entity Framework doesn't provide DeleteAsync or AddAsync. Why?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I just noticed that EF (using version 5 here) doesn't provide `DeleteAsync()`/`AddAsync()`. I also noticed that projects like this one:

https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus

do provide `DeleteAsync()` as an afterthought. Why doesn't EF provide `DeleteAsync()` out of the box? Just curious.

Addendum: As pointed out by the maintainer of EF-Plus the 'DeleteAsync' flavor I mentioned is somewhat different than 'Delete'/'DeleteAsync' of EF in the sense that the former operates on a query targeting elements that **will** be matched on the db/db-server, while EF's Delete operates on elements that **have already been retrieved before** 'Delete()' is invoked. Despite this difference in the signature of these methods the original concern raised by my question maintains its merit.

Comment: It does provide `Remove` and `SaveChangesAsync` though

Comment: When you do `Remove`, `Add`, `Update` in EF the changes are not preserved until you will run `SaveChanges`. It has its async analogue `SaveChangesAsync`

Comment: Hmmm.. I've never used that particular library, but looking at [their implementation of `DeleteAsync`](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/blob/master/src/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF5.NET40/BatchDelete/Extensions/DeleteAsync.cs) - you're not getting anything useful here.  Watch [the MSDN video about how async "library methods shouldn't lie"](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Async-Library-Methods-Shouldn-t-Lie).  The code in that library does exactly that.

Comment: Tip sent to library author here: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/131

Comment: +1 @MattJohnson thank you for tuning in and clearing up the confusion. The link you provided is solid gold. It's truly remarkable what one can learn by asking the simple questions these days! :)

Comment: That [whole video series](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async) is pretty amazing, if you really want to learn how to do async/await properly.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint The above link is no longer working as it now takes you to the [MicrosoftLearn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/channel9joinedmicrosoftlearn) page. Even if I Google the link it returns just goes to the same page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After watching the very enlightening material provided by MattJohnson and after probing into the implementation of Delete using reflection I surmised that the reason behind DeleteAsync() not being provided, is that delete causes the database to be changed within a single unit-of-work-instance-lifecycle.

*IF* someone provided a 'DeleteAsync()' operation through Task.Run() (aka **without a true async implementation**) this would effectively be inducing illusions through anti-patterns in the sense that developers would use this sort of API thinking they enjoy the benefits of 'true-async' but in reality they would *not* - they would only just suffer from unnecessary overhead ala 'await Task.Run(() => context.Foo.Delete(x))' without enjoying any benefits whatsoever.

TL;DR: The bottom-line explanation on why the folks of EF dont offer 'DeleteAsync()'/'AddAsync()' is that 'async methods shouldn't lie' (as MattJohnson pointed out) and 'DeleteAsync()'/'AddAsync()' would be bound to lie given the **current implementations** of EF at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

There is a huge difference between `Add` && `Remove` from Entity Framework and `Delete` from my library.

**Add/Remove**

The Add method will only add the entity to the ChangeTracker while the Remove method will only change the EntityState to "Deleted" in the ChangeTracker.

As @Ivan specified, the `Remove` doesn't save changes directly in the database until you call `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync`

**Delete**

This feature deletes rows from a database without loading entities in the context.

Calling this method may take quite some time depending on the number of rows that will be deleted in the database.

So, offering a `DeleteAsync` method can make sense here.

As @Matt specified, the library currently uses `Task.Run` instead of truly being async which will be eventually fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I Think the gist of all answers is that, `Remove()` method is not a *time-consuming operation* whereas it only changes a simple state in tracker, while the other counterparts e.g. `Find()` need to ping the Database which would be a time-consuming process.
On the other hand, methods like `AddAsync()` is made as its comment says:

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one
> used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo',
> to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method
> should be used.